# Secure my rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, oauth

I'm working on a basic rails API that I want to have secure.

I have a model Device with only attribute "status". Device belongs to a given user.

- The owner of this particular Device must be able to update it's status securely.
- Some other users must be able to read the status (but not update it) securely.

I was thinking of an OAuth approach:
- the device owner uses an authentication process to update the status
- the device users use a token to read its status

Is this a good approach ?
Is true, any advise on the gems to use ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this one and let me know if you find something more than this

http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast

Comment: Hi, I already saw this one but I was not really convinced. I'll give it a closer look.

Comment: yeah sure if you did not get it according to your needs, then lets discuss on something else :) awaiting for your applied technique